# S5 Note, locked, finger won't work, forget password

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note

I DO NOT want to lose my data/photos!
Finger won't work
Forgot back up password 
Never set up Samsung acc't
Can't access phone via Google/Gmail

Comment: It's not ideal but if there's no better suggestions it might be worth removing your sd card and seeing if your photos are there.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to **reset** your phone. You can try recovering photos from any data recovery app. No other way as you have no backup of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom recovery, you can at least do a nandroid backup then reset your phone. There are apps out there on play store that restore apps from nandroid backup. I have not tested those apps, but am aware they exist.